# Why is Splash not returning the same HTML as when I inspect a website?

Tags: lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

So I'm trying to get the html from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200116052415/https://www.livecoin.net/en/) website (notice it's an internet archive link). When inspecting the web page on a browser you can see that each row of the table is a `div` element with class `ReactVirtualized__Table__row tableRow___3EtiS`
But when I run a very simple LUA script on splash (in my browser) to get the html from that website I get something very different that does not contain `ReactVirtualized__Table__row tableRow___3EtiS`. Here is my code:

```
function main(splash, args)

    url = args.url
    assert(splash:go(url))
    assert(splash:wait(1))
    return splash:html()

end
```

Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it? Thanks!

---

ps: I know you don't need splash for just to get this specific html this is only the most basic version of the problem, no need to over-complicate.